# html5 fast 3d transformation

Tags: css, html, transformation

what is the fastest way to do a 3D transformation on a web page.
I need to rotate a plane about 50 degrees, and scroll it sideways.

I am doing this using CSS's transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(50deg);

when I scroll side ways, the frame rate drops dramatically.

Comment: I changed the code to use transition: transform 1s; and transform: translate(-npx);   where n is the number of pixel to scroll by. the performance is even worst. I'm moving a rather large div of 1536 pixels.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or the full code please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/SergioAntonio/nz6pyyop/  the speed is fine on a desktop, its on my iPhone, especially when I have multiples DIV scrolling on the screen. that the frame rate drops to about 15 frames per second, I want a minimum of 30 FPS.